# How to set different folder/file permission for differrent user names or user groups?

Tags: server, permissions, samba

I am migrating my home server from windows based to ubuntu based server. 
I am happy and satisfied with my Windows XP based file server and have been using it for about 6 years now.
 I am decommissioning the Windows XP
 server and wish to use my new linux server based on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop edition. I plan of using the server edition when I'll be satisfied with the desktop edition. 
But right now, I am having some problem with FILE PERMISSION in my new Ubuntu server.

In my Windows XP, I've shared a 4TB RAID0 array and the whole of it is shared within my workgroup. I have several users with different user permissions and I wanted this to be applied also in my Ubuntu server. But I am having some problem implementing it. Probably because of my lack of knowledge administering it.

Right now, In my Ubuntu server, I created a 4TB RAID Array and the whole of it is shared.

The contents of the RAID array is chowned recursively to `admin-one:users`.
The contents of the RAID array is chmoded recursively to 750.
In the server I have created the `user-one` and `user-two`account that belongs to `users` group.

In the shared RAID array, I have a folder called `restricted`.
Everything is setup well and runs fine with the client machine.

The problem now is, I have no idea on how shall I restrict `user-one` from accessing the `restricted` folder, since `user-one` belongs to `users` group that has read and execute permission for the whole contents of the RAID array and from where the `restricted` folder is located too. I can easily do this in windows, but not in Ubuntu.

To summarize the user's permissions:

admin-one - has read write execute permission to the whole shared partition.
user-one - has read and execute permission to the whole shared partition.
user-two - has read and execute permission to the whole shared partition.

**And what I want to accomplish is:**

user-one - has read and execute permission to the whole shared partition but shall have no access to the `restricted` folder.

user-two - has read and execute permission to the whole shared partition that includes the `restricted` folder, BUT shall have not write permission to the folder.

**So, the general question is, how shall I set different permissions to different users?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ACLs (a page to read about it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs).
ACLs work without any configuration needed at least in Ubuntu 13.04. I have no idea if they work in Ubuntu 12.04 straight away. If they don't, you could enable ACLs (search around how to do it) or ignore my answer.

- To restrict `user-one` from accessing the `restricted` folder, you could run the command:

  ```
  sudo setfacl -m u:user-one:- restricted
  ```
- To give `user-two` only read/write permission to the folder:

  ```
  sudo setfacl -m u:user-two:rw restricted
  ```
- To remove all ACLs from the folder:

  ```
  sudo setfacl -b restricted
  ```
- To view the ACLs of the folder:

  ```
  getfacl restricted
  ```

  Also, when you use the command `ls -l` to view the standard permissions of the folder, you will see an additional '+' in the permissions.

Again, I don't know if ACLs are enabled by default in Ubuntu 12.04.
If these commands fail, then ACLs are not enabled.

Comment: yes, it's enabled in 12.04. I'll dig further and apply those above.

Comment: thanks for introducing me to ACL, It got the job done!. It did not work in my first try. Then I did some further reading from the link above. Then I've enable acl support by adding acl option in my fstab for my RAID array. And It's working...